# RedirectToAction is not working correctly in SurfaceController?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, umbraco, umbraco7

I m submiting a form to SurfaceController's action 'Submit'. Where after saving data it Redirect to another action 'LeadContact' using MVC RedirectToAction and pass Id as a paramter to it. In 'LeadContact' model is being populating and passed to 'LeadContact' view.

Not sure if I m doing correctly or not but when 'LeadContact' renders in browser it amends URL. Browser shows URL like `http://name:50656/umbraco/Surface/HealthInsurance/LeadContact?leadOptionId=70` while I m expecting it should be

```
http://name:50656/HealthInsurance/LeadContact?leadOptionId=70
```

Can you please guide I can correct it ? Below is my code:

```
 public ActionResult Submit(FormCollection form)
        {

            //Some logic and later redirect to another action 'LeadContact'             

return RedirectToAction("LeadContact", new { leadOptionId = _id}); 
         }


 public ActionResult LeadContact(int leadOptionId)

        {
           MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel();         

           //Lines of code to populate data into model   

            return View("LeadContact", model);
        }
```

Thanks for your help and sharing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to remove /umbraco/surface/ from URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27369101/how-to-remove-umbraco-surface-from-url)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following rewrite rule to config\UrlRewriting.config:

```
<add name="LeadContactRewrite"
  virtualUrl="^/HealthInsurance/LeadContact(.*)"
  rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString"
  destinationUrl="~/umbraco/Surface/HealthInsurance/LeadContact?$1"
  ignoreCase="true" />
```

Recycle IIS and you should be able to go to `http://name:50656/HealthInsurance/LeadContact?leadOptionId=70` and get your desired outcome.

You could also look into [Custom MVC routing in Umbraco](http://shazwazza.com/post/Custom-MVC-routing-in-Umbraco)