# how to remove /umbraco/surface/ from URL?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7, umbraco-mvc

My Umbraco URL has `/umbraco/surface/` in them. For example:

```
http://localhost:50656/umbraco/Surface/HealthInsurance/Application?Pid=26665&Lid=73&Spid=23

http://localhost:50656/umbraco/Surface/HealthInsurance/Results/73
```

Is it possible to rewrite url for browser display and remove  `/umbraco/surface/` from it ?

I don't want to break just for browser display make url like one below:

```
   http://localhost:50656/HealthInsurance/Application?Pid=26665&Lid=73&Spid=23

    http://localhost:50656/HealthInsurance/Results/73
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set up custom routes in your Umbraco solution.

I can recommend this article on the subject: http://shazwazza.com/post/Custom-MVC-routing-in-Umbraco